# What is the origin of bengali Hindu Swastika?

Tags: identification-request, culture, symbols, swastika

[Swastika](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swastika) is an important symbol for almost all Dharmic faiths. Particularly in Hinduism, the symbol of Swastika is pretty much constant through out the world(unlike [Om](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Om) which have different symbol in different script like odia,tibetan, chinese etc).

Swastika has been constant even in china, korea and japan. But in bengal, it is drawn in a different manner.

Here are pictures of Bengali Hindu Swastika.

[image: first][image: second.].
As we can see,Bengali Hindu Swastika is different from the normal Swastika.Why so?

Comment: This is not the Bengali Swastika. It is probably drawn on Kalasa the holy pot? It possibly represents the Kalasa Devata.

Comment: @Rickross yes it is drawn on Kalasa. But in other parts of India, Swastika is drawn on Kalsa isn't it? Also, wikipedia refers it as Bengali Swastika.

Comment: Ok but I never heard this term "Bengali Swastika".

Comment: @Rickross are you bengali? If so it might be coz this symbol might be normal for you.

Comment: Yes I'm a Bengali.

Comment: @Rickross hmm.. that might be it. Here it is written as bengali Hindu Swastika on wikipedia page of bengali Hindus. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bengali_Hindus